# Throw ValueError for two digit year dates with dateutil.parser.parse

Tags: python, date, parsing, python-dateutil, 2-digit-year

While doing some data cleaning, I noticed that `dateutil.parser.parse` failed to reject a certain malformed date, thinking that the first number in it is a two digit year. Can this library be forced to treat two digit years as invalid?

Example:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('22-23 February')
```

outputs:

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 23, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to work around this by passing a custom `dateutil.parser.parserinfo` object via the `parserinfo` parameter to `dateutil.parser.parse`. Luckily, `dateutil.parser.parserinfo` has a `convertyear` method that can be overloaded in a derived class in order to perform extra validations on the year.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse, parserinfo

class NoTwoDigitYearParserInfo(parserinfo):
    def convertyear(self, year, century_specified=False):
        if year < 100 and not century_specified:
            raise ValueError('Two digit years are not supported.')
        return parserinfo.convertyear(self, year, century_specified)

parse('22-23 February', parserinfo = NoTwoDigitYearParserInfo())
```

outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1162, in parse
    return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 552, in parse
    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1055, in _parse
    if not info.validate(res):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 360, in validate
    res.year = self.convertyear(res.year, res.century_specified)
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in convertyear
ValueError: Two digit years are not supported.
```

Comment: Nice. I used this to prevent the year defaulting to current if no year found.

Comment: You're welcome! Another option is to pass `default = datetime(1900, 1, 1)` to `dateutil.parser.parse` (or whichever year you wish) and handle the dates with the default year afterwards.

Comment: I actually overrode the `validate` method, `if res.year is None: return False, else return super...`, seemed neat.